# StackOverflowError error while referring enum instance

Tags: java, enums

I'm wondering why I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when I do this

```
enum Grade { 
    A, B, C, D, F, INCOMPLETE;

    public String toString() {
        System.out.println(this); //<-- error here
        return "Name of enum: "+this.name()+"\n"+"Ordinal of enum: "+this.ordinal();
    }
};
```

Comment: Infinitely self-recursive non-static toString() via out.println(Object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easy. You call recursively `toString()` without end of recursion.

```
public String toString() {
    System.out.println(this); //<-- this will execute toString() again
}
```

If you pass some object as parameter, where String is expected, java will call its `toString()` method internally.

Comment: so like any other object, printing it calls it's toString()

Answer (score 3):

The following line in your code snippet:

```
System.out.println(this);
```

internally calls

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x); <---
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

which is defined as:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString(); <--- leads to recursive call
}
```

thus leads to `StackOverflowError`